# How to use camera with python in windows

Tags: camera, pygame

I am trying to use a camera in windows. I ve installed python with anaconda. tried installing pygame with conda but did not work so installed with pip. 
Following the advice in [open camera with pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29673348/how-to-open-camera-with-pygame-in-windows) I tried to open the camera but I got an error.

When executing `pygame.camera.init()` the system complains that can not import name _camera .

Indeed when reading camera.py there is the line `from pygame import _camera` and this is where it fails. It can not import _camera

I am at lost at what to do. Any help very much appreciated

EDIT1:

I have been told that this works in linux only. :( 
So going to the title question: How to use the camera with python in windows?  (or mac?)

Answer (score 0):

PyGame Doc: [camera](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/camera.html)

> Pygame currently supports only Linux and v4l2 cameras.

It means it works only with Linux.

Comment: Thanks!. Does this mean that it does not work on a mac either? and Is there a way to use the camera with python for linux?

Comment: try [OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_tutorials.html) and [Getting Started with Videos](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html#display-video)